# IE 8 and javascript debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I upgrade my IE last week, and now i can't disabled the javascript debugger for visual studio 2008. The checkbox in the IE options are uncheck but the debugger in visual studio still enable.

Any idea ?

ps : I got Ie 8.0.6001.18783

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 'feature' of VS2008 - there's no way to turn it off.

You can, however, open the Processes window (Alt-Z by default) and detach VS2008 from iexplore.exe after it's launched.

Comment: But the problem is with internet explorer 7 when de disable javascript debugger was activate, the process was detach automaticly. With ie 8 it's dont work properly

Comment: That's correct - with IE8, there's no wait to do what you want.  VS2008 will always attach to IE8, regardless of the state of the 'disable javascript debugging' setting.

C'est correct - avec ie8, il n'y a aucun méthode pour faire ce que vous voulez - VS2008 s'attachera toujours à IE8, n'importe la valeur du setting 'disable javascript debugger'.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to debug javascript.

There is [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306232/how-debug-javascript-with-ie-8)