# Console.log in IE on an object just outputted [object Object]

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

I'm used to debugging JavaScript in Chrome or Firefox just because their built in developer tools are a lot cleaner than IE's. IE8 came along way with the Developer Tools being more polished, but they're still not completely up to snuff. I like being able to step through code as if I was in Visual Studio, and that is pretty nice about IE, however, when trying to do a simple console.log on an object that I have, in Firefox/Chrome/etc. I can actually explore that object.

In IE, the console is simply outputting the following:

LOG: [object Object]

Is there any way to drill down into that object in IE like in Chrome/Firefox/etc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I dump JavaScript vars in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956384/how-do-i-dump-javascript-vars-in-ie8)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306232/how-to-debug-javascript-with-ie-8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you can try what Xavi suggested here: [How do I dump JavaScript vars in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956384/how-do-i-dump-javascript-vars-in-ie8)

Comment: Yeah, this is great for debugging, but not completely what I was looking for.

Comment: Could you add the answer to your questions? Other sites go down, change etc, and can't be edited.

Answer (score 52):

You might want to try:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(foobarObject));
```

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding this wrong but if I type "console.log('foo')" into the entry field at the bottom of the console window, the console (text area above) says:

 >>console.log('foo')
 undefined

Comment: It should also have the message "LOG: foo". console.log returns undefined which is what it outputs in the console as well. In IE9 that was changed to not show undefined results in the console.

Comment: does not print anything for xml object, but `console.dir(obj);` does

Answer (score 32):

Use:

```
console.dir(obj);
```

This will will give you all properties of the object also in IE.

Comment: Note: console.dir shows only the first level of properties.
So when you would create var a = { a: 'b', b : { a: 'b', b : 'c'}}, the result of console.dir(a) would be: {
 a : "b",
 b : [object Object]
}

Comment: Yes, not so useful for any objects which are classes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add the object to watch and you can see and analyze it completely from watch panel.