# document.getElementById("ID") returns Object in IE11 and Dom element in edge

Tags: javascript, dom, querying

`document.getElementById("ViewSearchBar")` is returning Dom object like `[object Object]` in IE11, where as the same query Returns Dom element in Edge like `<span id='ID'>`. Hence I am confused, as properties and methods differ on the way the output is rendered. Also please let me know why we see that difference.

Comment: It is _not_ returning `[object object]` in IE11, IE11 just does not print these elements as anything other than that description. In memory, its the same object and it works the same. `[object object]` is printed by IE since that is its description, since IE's console does not log anything but direct values. For example, an array in IE11 is `[object array]` and not `[1,2,3]`... Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434613/console-log-in-ie-on-an-object-just-outputted-object-object

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is being seen in developer tools, EX:document.getElementById("ViewSearchBar").all is working fine in IE11, but the same breaks in edge, as its returning Tag. Please let me know if i am missing something

Comment: What is `.all` on a node and what is it supposed to do? I have honestly never seen this before. The reason this is important is because it makes no sense to have something called `all` in a single selector function. It either returns ONE node or NONE. I cannot find the `.all` in any documentation, so let me know what it is for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid. Here its mentioned about document.all

Comment: This might help : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/009df27c-04bf-453c-bd80-c56eb6fbb6f5/howto-replace-elementall-for-ie11-and-previous-ie-versions?forum=iewebdevelopment

Comment: Then what is this ungodly mix of both supposed to do anyhow (`document.getElementById("ViewSearchBar").all`)? Have a look into non-proprietary web technologies like `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` and **forget about things like _all_**.