# How do I view an JavaScript object in IE8's Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

How do I view a Javascript object in IE8's Developer Tools? In WebKit and Firebug, I can fire a command at the console which returns an object and it'll show me a tree of the object that I can navigate. In Internet Explorer, all I get is:

```
>>getSelection();
{...}
```

Is there a way to get a similar tree view in IE8's Developer Tools that I'm missing, or should I try and use something else (Firebug Lite maybe?) instead?

Comment: Doesn't IE8 show `console.log()` output just like Firebug? I can be wrong but I thought it did. (**Edit:** It doesn't.)

Comment: That returns this:

    >>console.log(getSelection());
    LOG:
    undefined

Comment: yeah, it doesn't, I checked too.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956384/how-do-i-dump-javascript-vars-in-ie8 maybe better than nothing. **Edit:** Oh, asked by me, incidentally! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

near the console you can see standart watcher
dblclick on empty field and just type your variable

Comment: Do you mean the Watch tab above the console on the right hand side of the window? I can't figure out how to add stuff to that...

Comment: Pekka linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956384/how-do-i-dump-javascript-vars-in-ie8 above, and that shows that your solution works, I just need to click "Start Debugger", and then type "debugger" into the console first. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome!! :) Thanks!