# confused by the javascript console log output of function variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner when it comes to `javascript/jquery`..so if this question sounds silly,please forgive me.

While going through [this tutorial](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) ,I tried to write to javascript `console` ,values of some of the variables in the functions-so that I can better understand how the function works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.post h2 a").click(function () {
    var a    = $(this),
    href = a.attr('href'),
    content  = a.parent().next();
    console.log('a='+a);
    console.log('a.get(0)='+a.get(0));
    console.log('a parent='+a.parent());
    console.log('a parent.get(0)='+a.parent().get(0));
    console.log("href="+href);
    console.log('content='+content);
    content.load(href + " #content");
    return false; 
});
```

I have modified the html slightly

```
<div class="post">
    <h2 id="h21"><a href="other/mypage.html">My Page</a></h2>
    <div class="content">
        Teaser text1...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
    <h2 id="h22"><a href="other/myotherpage.html">My Other Page</a></h2>
    <div class="content">
        Teaser text2...
    </div>
</div>
});
```

when I click on the first link,I get this console log output

```
a=[object Object]
a.get(0)=file:///home/me/dev/misc/other/mypage.html
a parent=[object Object]
a parent.get(0)=[object HTMLHeadingElement]
href=other/mypage.html
content=[object Object]
```

I thought the  `$(this)` expression in the function would be the element which was clicked(ie the first `<a element`).Why does it appear as [object Object].I couldn't make out how `a.get(0)` becomes `file:///home/me/dev/misc/other/mypage.html`

Similarly,shouldn't the variable `content` be equal to the first  `div` (containing Teaser text1)? Why does it appear as [object Object]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought the $(this) expression in the function would be the element
>   which was clicked(ie the first <a element).Why does it appear as
>   [object Object].

The variable `a` contains a jQuery object, and the `toString` method isn't overridden for it, so it uses the default implementation that returns the type of the object.

> I couldn't make out how a.get(0) becomes
>   file:///home/me/dev/misc/other/mypage.html

The `get` methods returns DOM element objects from the jQuery object, and the `toString` method for an `<a>` element returns the URL that the link points to.

> Similarly,shouldn't the variable content be equal to the first div
>   (containing Teaser text1)? Why does it appear as [object Object]?

The variable `content` contains a jQuery element that contains the `<div>` element. Using `content.get(0)` would give you the DOM element.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between these two lines:

```
console.log(content);
console.log('content=' + content);
```

The first just logs the `content` variable. The second does a concatenation operation, concatenating the string and the object, before logging it. Concatenating a string and an object results in the object's `toString` method being called, which results in `[object Object]`. To avoid this, don't do the concatenation and just log `content` directly. As mindandmedia comments, you can do this by passing the values as separate arguments to `console.log`:

```
console.log('content=', content);
```

Finally, any native DOM link element with an `href` attribute does have a `toString` method. This returns the `href` value. So `console.log('a.get(0)=' + a.get(0))` gets the `href` value of the first element in the `a` set.

Comment: this, and also pro tip: you can log multiple things in one call by using commas: `console.log('content=',content);

Comment: Does your tip work for IE? In IE8's Developer tools using console.log('object=', object) still gives output like "LOG: object=[object Object]".

Comment: @GuruM I believe IE's console just calls `toString` on everything. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956384/how-do-i-dump-javascript-vars-in-ie8) for where this has come up before.

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is a jQuery object, which is why it shows as [object Object]. All jQuery select functions return a jQuery object. As above, you can use .html() to get the HTML of a jQuery object, or .text() to just get the text.

It's because jQuery is chainable so you can do things like $(this).next().parent() etc etc. Each "chain" returns a jQuery object that can then have another function run on it.

Edit:

As a side note, you can use $(this)[0] to return the DOM Element I believe

Answer (score 0):

try removing the strings from each of your consoles so that you only output the actual variable.

e.g. replace:

```
console.log('a='+a);
```

with

```
console.log(a);
```

and so on.