# IE7 & IE8 error executing function with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading an ajax page which executes an HTML5 video player script. The function for the Flash fallback is `html5media();` :

```
//Load 1st Case Study
    $("#splash").live('click', function (e) {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#case-studies').load('case-study-1.html', function() {
               html5media(); //initiate Flash fallback
            }).fadeIn();

        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

This initial page load works fine in IE7 & IE8.

The problem is once this page is loaded, there are links to 4 more videos which are loaded in again using ajax. I use this function:

```
//Switcher
function csClients(url, client) {
    $("#case-studies").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#case-studies').load(url, function () {
            html5media(); //initiate Flash fallback
        }).fadeIn();
    });
}

//Page Loader
$("#cs-client-list li.client1 a").live('click', function(e) {
    csClients('case-study-1.html', 'client1');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Originally I was using `return false;` but none of the sub-page Flash videos would load in IE7. When I switched to preventDefault, the videos loaded in IE7 but still not in IE8.

I also get a weird error in both IE7 & IE8 with no helpful feedback:

Error on Page:

Unspecified error.

/ (Line 49)

Code: 0 (Char 5) URI:

http://www.mysite.com

This is line 49 in my index page:

```
<section id="case-studies" class="main-section">
```

I have a feeling it has to do with calling html5media(); too many times? At a loss...

Comment: For what it's worth -- the section element isn't supported in either IE 7 or 8

Comment: I'm using modernizr. Could that not be working in this instance? If I comment out html5media(); the error goes away.

Comment: Could it have to do with html5media(); running in #case-studies and then re-running in the same div when the other ajax pages load?

Comment: You could test if it's Ajax or `html5media()` by manually calling `html5media();` a few times in a row.

Comment: What is in `html5media()`?  Call it on its own and make sure the AJAX requests, element fading and other DOM manipulations aren't interfering.

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue in IE 8, leverage the [developer toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306232/how-to-debug-javascript-with-ie-8) to inspect your "Unspecified error". Any information you can provide from that tool might help us answer your question.

Comment: another idea is to put a try - catch block around html5media()

Comment: I ran into the same problem a while back. Incoming HTML5 content was torn apart in IE<9. Our solution at the time was to revert to XHTML markup for the AJAX-able content :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a problem with the html5media plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with using the browser's `domNode.innerHTML` impelementation for incoming AJAX content. There's a plugin ([innerShiv](http://jdbartlett.com/innershiv/)) that supposedly fixes the issue. (Full disclosure, I've never tried the plugin.)

And according to the plugin's homepage, the issue is fixed in jQuery 1.7, so you might try updating your jQuery reference instead.

Comment: I was using jQuery 1.7.1 so not sure that's the problem. I believe it had something to do with the plugin I was using (html5media). I switched to an entirely different video player script (MediaElement.js) and no longer had the problem. (Although I had to entirely recode that section.)