# ie8 'Invalid Pointer'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, coffeescript

I have a function written in coffeescript that used to work fine but now throws an 'Invalid Pointer' exception in ie8.

The Coffee Script

```
convertSVGforIE = ->

  if not $.support.svg or device.ff36
    imagesToConvert = $('img.SVG')
    imagesToConvert.each ->
      imageSrcMinus = this.src.substr 0, this.src.length - 3
      this.src = imageSrcMinus + 'png'
```

The Javascript

```
convertSVGforIE = function() {
    var imagesToConvert;
    if (!$.support.svg || device.ff36) {
      imagesToConvert = $('img.SVG');
      return imagesToConvert.each(function() {
        var imageSrcMinus;
        imageSrcMinus = this.src.substr(0, this.src.length - 3); //Invalid pointer
        return this.src = imageSrcMinus + 'png';
      });
    }
};
```

I can't see anything wrong with my script. Please help me determine, what is ie8's problem.

UPDATE:
I got this to work, but not in a good way

```
convertSVGforIE = ->

  if not $.support.svg or device.ff36
    $('img.SVG').each ->
      that = $(this)
      imageSrcMinus = that.attr('src').substr 0, that.attr('src').length - 3
      that.attr 'src', imageSrcMinus+'png'
```

The above script works, but why does $(this).attr('src') work? while this.src does not? And why only in IE?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in and see what this.src and this.src.length are; on the line that generates the error.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by breakpoint. Can you link me to some documentation?

Comment: Here's another stack overflow question detailing the debugging of Javascript in IE8;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306232/how-to-debug-javascript-with-ie-8.

Comment: As to the why's; it's because sadly there is still no formal compliance of Javascript features between any of the major browser implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534643(v=vs.85).aspx, it says that

1. You can only do `elem.src` from IE8 or later, and
2. Exactly how this works depends on whether you're in IE8 Standards Mode or Compatibility Mode.

If you look at the comments on that page, there are other quirks as well..

Using jQuery is certainly the easiest fix here, with the pleasant side effect of IE6-7 compatibility, but you may also want to try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

to the head of the page to force IE8 into Standards Mode.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the .src property of an image is supported in all versions of IE. That MSDN documentation is quite confusing, since it does seem to imply that the property is only supported in IE8 or later; but that's wrong.

However the invalid pointer error occurs in IE8 when you try to read the .src of an image which has a data URI larger than 4K. This bug is documented at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2688188 and the recommended fix is to update your browser.

But there is a simple workaround, which is to refer to the SRC in the image attributes collection, i.e. instead of this:

```
img.src
```

use this:

```
img.attributes.src.value
```