# Which mode is cross-compatible with JSP

Tags: internet-explorer, jsp, firefox, google-chrome, tomcat

I am designing my website in `jsp`. i am using `Apache tomcat` server to run my website. My website is running and rendering perfectly in `Firefox` and `Chrome`. However in `Internet Explorer 8` it is abnormally behaving.
In Internet Explorer some modes are present to view the web. My question is that which `mode` is cross compatible and highly acceptable across the web developers for designing web pages with `jsp`?

Comment: Edit your question and add this information: Which version of IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this has nothing to do with JSPs. JSPs are just a way to mix Java and HTML code. There must be something in the HTML code that IE8 doesn't like.

Setting the mode to quirks or standards mode might help but there is no mode in which all browsers will behave the same. Still, you can find a complete discussion about browser modes here: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

What else can you try?

- Use the developer tools built into IE8 (see this answer: [How to debug Javascript with IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306232/how-to-debug-javascript-with-ie-8)) to check whether IE8 gives you any error messages in the console.
- Add debug information in your app to see what happens around the code that seems broken
- Ask a question without the words "abnormally behaving". Instead, tell us what you see and what you expect and we might be able to help.