# How to debug script execution timeouts in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am developping a fairly complex kendo-ui web application with knockout.js databinding. while the app runs fine on modern systems, it triggers script execution timeouts on slower systems (the famous "there is a long-running javascript on this page - do you want to stop it ?" dialog).

This warning appears after the model has been bound with `ko.applyBindings()`.My only hint is that the script stops at `ko.utils.arrayIndexOf`, as the affected browser is IE8 I haven't been able to extract a meaningful stack trace, I'm using knockout 2.2.1.

What is the best strategy to debug these issues? I would be glad to know which widget/binding causes the timeout.

Comment: I assume you are working with the development file?

Comment: yes, I'm working with the development file

Comment: Just checking, but I assume (yet again) you are aware of Chrome's Web tools that allow you to debug your JavaScript?

Comment: Anzeo, the problem with the timeout is that it doesn't appear on all browsers and systems. So far I could only reproduce it on an IE8 running in a vm. However I could track it down to some knockout-validation stuff.

Comment: Pain in the *rse, I read over the IE8 part. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306232/how-to-debug-javascript-with-ie-8