# how to read parsed json data in ajax success call

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jquery

On Ajax success call, I'm getting already parsed data in JSON format from a Controller.
I want to read that data, so while I'm doing below one, I am getting `undefined` as an error.
How can I solve this?

```
success : function(response) { 
    alert(response.operatorId); 
},
```

Comment: success : function(response) {
      alert(response.operatorId);
     },   this is the function where m getting error aS UNDEFINED

Comment: Please add your code and an example of the JSON response to your question.

Comment: success : function(response) { alert(response.operatorId); },

Comment: What is the JSON format? Without seeing that we can't help.

Comment: are you specifying `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: errorMsg
 null
 
loanCollection
 [Object { alfKey=10, loanNumber="00095203", propertyName="WALGREEN", more...}, Object { alfKey=14, loanNumber="00022208", propertyName="CROWN POINT PLAZA (KROGER)", more...}, Object { alfKey=21, loanNumber="00026263", propertyName="PUBLIX CENTER - JACKSONVILLE", more...}, 15 more...]
 
operatorId
 "29299600"
 
operatorName
 "Kathy, McDow"
 
password
 null

Comment: Take a browser that has a javascript-debugger and set breakpoints and debug the data at hand ... How do you f.e. know, that you get already parsed JSON data - and who/what's your _Spring controller_? Or what does it have to do with the client-side of your application?

Comment: {

    "operatorName": "Kathy, McDow",
    "operatorId": "29299600",
    "password": null,
    "loanCollection": [
        {
            "alfKey": 10,
            "loanNumber": "00095203",
            "propertyName": "WALGREEN",
            "loanSubmissionDate": "",
            "formName": "Lodging",
            "entryStatus": "N"
        }
        
    ],
    "errorMsg": null

}

Comment: can't you simply call $.getJSON?

Comment: spring controller already giving me response body i.e returning model in json format

Comment: actually here we are using backbonejs collection concept

Comment: yes m specifying content type

Comment: Use console.log(response) to display it in console and show the output

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of working code

```
 success: function(json) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(json.topics));
   $.each(json.topics, function(idx, topic){
     $("#nav").html('<a href="' + topic.link_src + '">' + topic.link_text + "</a>");
   });
 }
```

Comment: still getting undefined

Comment: Please update you question so that it contains all relevant and up-to-date information

Answer (score 0):

It appears  that the response  coming into success function is not a JSON object. COuld you check if you have following set in  your ajax call.

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType : 'application/json'
```

Alternatively, you may use the following to parse the  json string to json object and then use dot notation to access the properties

```
success : function(response) { 
    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(response)
    alert(jsonData.operatorId); 
},
```

Comment: i already tried with this, its showing me message as already parsed in json format

Comment: you could you debugger and put a breakpoint on the alert call. Inspect the JSON that you are getting by adding a watch. This is how I usually attempt to solve freaky JS problems :). Might find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306232/how-to-debug-javascript-with-ie-8  or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx