# php code does not work on IE 8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

***RESOLVED:: `<div id="slideshow"> <?php echo implode(' ',$images); ?> </div> TO >>> <div id="slideshow"> <div> <?php echo implode(' ',$images); ?> </div> </div>`***

I have my html/php code running in all new versions of browsers (chrome,firefox,IE 11...), but when I try to make it run on IE 8 it does not work properly! It actually a very simle code i search in an excel file for a certain users whom their birthday date = today's date. Then get their pictures in a slideshow.

This is the code:

```
<?php
/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$goal = date ('d/m');
$row_counter=0;
$images = array();
$names = array();
$exists_counter=0;

try{
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("employe.xlsx");
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
$row_counter++;
$bday = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(21,$row_counter)->getFormattedValue();
$ToCompare =substr($bday, 0, 5);
// foreach ($cellIterator as $cell){
if ($goal== $ToCompare){
$name = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$row_counter)->getFormattedValue();
$sex = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$row_counter)->getFormattedValue();
$id = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$row_counter)->getFormattedValue();
$imagename = 'imgs/'.$id.'.jpg';

  if (file_exists($imagename)){
       $images[]='<left><img id='.$exists_counter.' src="imgs/'.$id.'.jpg"  align="middle" border=1 height="470" width="310">BONNE ANNIVERSAIRE!<br> '.$name.'</left><br>';
    }else{
    if($sex== "m" or $sex== "M"){

    $images[]='<left><img id='.$exists_counter.' src="imgs/male.jpg" align="middle" border=1 height="470" width="310">BONNE ANNIVERSAIRE!<br>'.$name.'</left><br>';
    }else{
    $images[]='<left><img id='.$exists_counter.' src="imgs/female.jpg" align="middle" border=1 height="470" width="310">BONNE ANNIVERSAIRE!<br>'.$name.'</left><br>';
    }       
} 
$exists_counter++;
  }
 }
  }catch(Exception $e){
  echo 'MERCI DE VERIFIER l’INTEGRITE DU FICHIER Excel!!! ', "\n";
  }
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Birthday Slider</title>

 <style type="text/css">
 #slideshow{
width: 312px;
height: 550px;
    overflow: hidden;
background-image: url(imgs/loader.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.wideskyhosting.com/js/jquery.cycle.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#slideshow").cycle({ 
 fx:      'custom', 
 sync: 0, 
 cssBefore: {  
    top:  0, 
    left: 320, 
    display: 'block' 
 }, 
 animIn:  { 
    left: 0 
 }, 
 animOut: {  
    top: 550 
 }, 
 delay: 0,
 timeout: 6500
 });
 })
 </script>
 </head>
 <body style="font-family: Arial, Sans-serif, sans;">
<div id="slideshow">
    <?php echo implode(' ',$images); ?>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with browser !!

Comment: PHP doesn't depend on browser.

Comment: check the javascript console for errors

Comment: i am a noob, what i think the problem is its a jquery problem and i do not have any idea to get over it, i tried to use : <!--[if lt IE 9]>[...]<![endif]--> but it does not work for me therefore either i did not use it properly or it is not the problem

Comment: just give link to your Website URL

Comment: See when you open the page , Then Right click on that page , click on View page Source ,Then copy that data ,And then post that data In updated answer.So we can test it on our IE . Do it.It has nothing to do with PHP.Its JQuery

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned php has nothing to do with your browser. 
Try opening the console of your browser (IE 8) and see if there are any javascript syntax errors.

Here is a link on How to debug javascript with IE8
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306232/how-to-debug-javascript-with-ie-8)

**Edit**

You are using an extraneous **left** tag that doesn't exist in the DOM. IE8 is very sensitive when it comes to HTML markup and thus it won't display or will display your HTML code but with errors.
Try removing those tags and align your images using CSS.

Comment: , The User has no javascript in his code ,can u see?

Comment: what i exactly mentioned and the debugger shows no errors

Comment: Are you using a **left** tag in your php script?

Comment: yes i do i need my slider to be in the top left corner

Comment: I wasn't able to find any documentation on the left tag you are using. Such tag doesn't exist in the DOM.
http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags

there are other ways of aligning elements using CSS.

Comment: I'm with @user3529729, get rid of your <left></left> tags and re-run.

Comment: RESOLVED:: 
<div id="slideshow">
    <?php echo implode(' ',$images); ?>
</div>

TO >>>

<div id="slideshow">
   <div> <?php echo implode(' ',$images); ?> </div> 
</div>