# Website functioning on all browsers except Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

So i just finished up my website and uploaded it (New-ish web dev, please don't be to harsh). It works fine on all browsers except IE8. The website has a lot to load (images, etc.) so it is white screen for 1 - 2 seconds then fades into the actual site. On IE8    (IE9 + works just fine) the page stays on the white 'loading' screen forever. I have a lot of code here and I'm just wondering what you professional web developers here think i should do!

Website URL: http://cydronix.kkhorram.info/

Comment: Welcome to the wondrous world of web development. And welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some relevant HTML and CSS/JS code so we know what is going on.

Comment: Could you put what functionality is not working ?

Comment: @PrashantSarvaiya None of the page is loading(IE8). Normally it would be white screen for 1 - 2 seconds max to load the page, then it would fade into the actual website(All other browsers). But Internet Explorer 8 is stuck at that white screen.

Comment: Could you please check in console if there is any javascript error. May be few of the jquery functions doesn't support in IE8.

Comment: @jao I'm not sure what to post, It's taken me a very long time to post this and a lot of different files (several HTML, CSS & JS files)

Comment: @PrashantSarvaiya I checked the console, there are no errors.

Comment: post the CSS and javascript that does the animation

Comment: @User888999—are you using jQuery? It loves to hide errors and fail silently. Very handy.

Comment: Check your jQuery version, be sure to use http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js

Answer (score 0):

There is two options: forget about IE8 or make it work on IE8.

Sounds like you have a problem with your javascript. To debug javascript on IE8, read this [How to debug Javascript with IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306232/how-to-debug-javascript-with-ie-8).

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your included `.js` files causing the issue. Check for the compatibility of your used javascript files

Answer (score 0):

You said you uploaded the site - could you post the link if its live - otherwise without seeing some code the issue if difficult

Comment: Added the URL to the post.