# Break point is not hitting in javascript file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, internet-explorer-8

I'm facing some trouble on break point in Visual Studio 2013 update2

**What the issue is:**

I'm having a place where the button has to Submit. On submitting of button, I need to call a java script function, later it should go to some function in c#. This is the work flow. Here, I kept a break point on a line in JS file, and C#. Now, on submitting, the break point hits the js line but it suddenly disappear and move to c# line.

**What I tried is:**

As soon as i got this error, i start to surf in google. After a long time i found the below things to resolve. But none helps me to come out of this issue.

1. I restarted My Visual Studio
2. I wrote 'debugger' in the place of breakpoint line.
3. I unchecked silverlight in solution properties window.
4. Added TabProcGrowth  in Registry Editor.

I tested in IE8 and chrome. Nothing works.

I updated my IE8 version to IE11 version in one of my friend's system. It's working fine there.

**What I want is:**

I want to able to check the place where i inserted break point in my Java Script file using VS2013 and IE8. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** Break point is hitting but it's not standing for more than 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: use debugger in javascript..just write "debugger;" in javascript function

Comment: Is your debug javascript enabled in IE ?

Comment: @sangramparmar I wrote in javascript function only.

Comment: @Shrivallabh. Yes i enabled that too. I forgot to mention it in my question. I made unchecked in internet options.

Comment: Provide more code, details, type of broswer, ??

Comment: What code you're expecting here ?. Type of browser ?. I tested in IE8 and chrome.

Comment: Please provide your code for help

Comment: @User125  What code you' re expecting here ?. I'm asking for Breakpoint

Comment: @ gkrishy ,if  you are getting error 400 means there may be mistake in your code. so that is way I want to see you javascript code and also want to see  how you are calling  that  function .

Comment: @User125 I'm not getting any error. My issue is abou the breakpoint is not hitting javascript file. Consider I'm having alert function in my javascript(I kept breakpoint here). On button click am calling this function. On immediate click, I should redirect to javascript file with red line marking. But, Here I'm not getting this. Hope you got my issue now.

Comment: put break point in c# code and `alert`s in javascript. still not working then add `firebug` in your browser. run your project and see `script` errors in your console of `firebug` javascript error can be catch easily with that. let me know if this works or not.

Comment: use firebug for debug the js file

Comment: @DinavAhire Go through my question once again. I want my issue to resolve in IE(IE 8).

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj Go through my question once again. I want my issue to resolve in IE(IE 8)

Comment: @gkrishy: Are u using any Ajax post method in your code??

Comment: are your breakpoints for javascript in Visual Studio? or Developer Window?

Comment: @jackjop at visual studio

Comment: Hi @gkrishy, can you provide some code where breakpoint is not hit?

Answer (score 4):

Even you Can debug your Code in Chrome also please follow these steps and tell me the Outcome..

1.Keep the 'debugger' to the function where you want to fire the Debug Point.

2.Now open the Chrome and Press F12 (Developer Tools)

3. Click on "Sources"

Now try to open the Page where the java script function exists.. automatically debugging mode will be fired and you can see what actually happens, (Any Errors in script )

Comment: I agree, chrome is better to debug javascript.  Come on Microsoft! Get your *hit together!

Comment: @webruster +1 for new way for new idea, thanks for that. And I'm able to identify the exact issue in all the ways except one way that's what I need. I'm having IE8, i need to check my break point with the help of IE8. If i do upgrade to IE11 then it's working fine. My question is why not in IE8 ?

Comment: All versions of IE since IE8 use [two or more processes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/11/ie8-and-loosely-coupled-ie-lcie.aspx): One process is the Manager/Frame process and one or more processes represent the tab/content processes where your HTML and script run. You want your debugger to attach to the tab/content process, which is a child of the manager/frame process. The "Do you want to debug" prompt is controlled by Tools > Internet Options > Advanced; see the 2 "Script debugger" check boxes near the top of the list. (Unable to add source.. my comment character limit exceeded)

Comment: debugger is a cumbersome workaround and not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Is your JS break point outside of the context of your AJAX request? If so, is the AJAX request firing before your break-pointed JS line?

If so it may scan over the AJAX request and select your JS break-point... until the AJAX request (fired previously) is received by the C# class which then over-rides the previous break-point set inside VS?

AJAX isn't synchronous, so it'll fire the request the continue procedural down the rest of the function, and deal with the result of the AJAX request when it's received.

Comment: Is this really an answer? Comments are for gathering information. Answers are        for solutions.   Everything you wrote belongs in comments.

Answer (score 0):

1. First ensure there is no JavaScript related errors on the page
2. Ensure your AJAX call is not firing before hitting to breakpoint
3. Check your JavaScript related settings on your browser (according to you, this was working on your friend's machine)

Answer (score 0):

The **`debugger`** keyword

Supported in the following document modes:

Quirks, Internet Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards, Internet Explorer 8 standards, Internet Explorer 9 standards, Internet Explorer 10 standards, Internet Explorer 11 standards. Also supported in Store apps (Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1). See Version Information.

Also go for more information

[How to debug Javascript with IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306232/how-to-debug-javascript-with-ie-8)